# How to see error info and debug info from Apache server?

Tags: apache, cgi

Nowadays when running WAMP or MAMP (or the default web server on a Mac), whenever there is error from the CGI file (such as Ruby or PHP), the error message is not shown (and no line number either).  Is there a way to run the web server in a shell so that any error message is shown?

The one I am trying to show is on a Mac's built-in web server.  (maybe it is a little different in other MAMP or WAMP platforms)

Comment: isn't there an error log file that can be found in install directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the errors of CGI scripts in **/var/log/apache2/error_log** for the default web server on apache.

You can view realtime results using :

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log
```

Comment: it works, although it can be good if it is running inside a shell so all the output is immediate.  thanks.